# How do you determine the Scoville units of a salsa made with 3 kinds of peppers?

Tags: chili-peppers, spicy-hot, capsaicin

Do you add each Scoville unit of each and the grand total is your answer  or add each Scoville unit and divide the grand total by 3?
Example Jalapeno 2,500 SHU + Serrano 10,000 SHU +Arbol 15,000 =27,500 SHU or 27,500/3= 9,166 SHU. I just need an estimate :)

Comment: Are the proportions exactly equal, or are there different amounts of the different peppers?

Comment: Definitely a duplicate of the other question.  See the answer there.  To sum up: that's not how scoville works.